# How to find a file and delete containing some string in the body using awk command from multiple files?

Tags: shell, awk

I have multiple files in the file directory `Record`:

```
Record
   1.txt
   2.txt
   3.txt
```

The file `2.txt` contains a string `abcd` in the second column of the first line. How can I print all the contents in `2.txt`?
How can I delete the file 2.txt?

I used `awk` to print all the contents in that file but it only prints that line.

I used `find` command to store the file name in the `file.txt` folder but it gives me an error.

```
rm -rf Record
mkdir Record
cd Record
echo f1
touch 1.txt
echo author: efg   > 1.txt
echo title: hijk  >> 1.txt
echo pages: 1990  >> 1.txt
echo year: 1890  >> 1.txt
touch 2.txt
echo author: abcd > 2.txt
echo author: lmno >> 2.txt
echo title: pqrs >> 2.txt
echo pages: 354 >> 2.txt
echo year:  1970 >> 2.txt
touch 3.txt
echo author: aklj > 3.txt
echo title: dban  >> 3.txt
echo pages: 876  >> 3.txt
echo year: 1860  >> 3.txt
cd ..
adress=./Record/*.txt
sfind=abcd
  awk ' BEGIN { sfind = ENVIRON["sfind"] }
    FNR == 1 { secondPass = seen[FILENAME]++ }
    secondPass { print FILENAME, $0; next }
    index($2,sfind) {
        ARGV[ARGC] = FILENAME
        ARGC++
        nextfile       
    }
'
$adress
```

Comment: The awk commands in your question contain syntax and semantic errors. When asking for help with a command it's important to show the actual command.

Comment: Please specify the column separator(s?).

Comment: Apparently based on you saying `How to find a file` and the example you provided you're getting some answers (see the `cat "$(grep ...)"` answers) that assume you will **always** find the string you're looking for in 1 file, it'll never not be present in any file, and it will never be present in 2 or more files. If that's a correct assumption you should update your answer to state that. If that's an incorrect assumption you should update your answer to state that those cases can occur and how you'd want them handled.

Comment: You're also getting some answers that are doing regexp instead of string matching, presumably because although you said "How to find a file containing some **string**" you then showed examples that use regexp `/.../` instead of string `"..."` delimiters. So please also update your question to clarify if you're trying to do regexp or string matching and, while you're at it, if you want to to whole field, whole "word", or partial matching (e.g. does `the` match `there`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sfind='abcd' awk '
    BEGIN { sfind = ENVIRON["sfind"] }
    FNR == 1 { secondPass = seen[FILENAME]++ }
    secondPass { print FILENAME, $0; next }
    index($2,sfind) {
        ARGV[ARGC++] = FILENAME
        nextfile        # for efficiency if using GNU gawk.
    }
' ./Record/*.txt
```

The above makes 2 passes of the input files - the first pass to identify those that contain the value of the string stored in `sfind` in `$2` and add them back into the and of ARGV[] so they'll be processed again later, the second to print the contents of those files identified on the first pass. If you don't want the input file name printed at the start of each output line then just change `print FILENAME, $0` to `print`.

The above will work for any number of matches in any number of files (0, 1, 2, whatever), for any file names, even if they contain spaces, globbing characters, etc., and for any characters in `sfind` including backslash escapes and regexp metcharacters like `.` or `*`.

The above does partial string matching. Here are your options:

- Partial string: `index($2,sfind)` (as shown)
- Full field string: `$2 == sfind`
- Partial regexp: `$2 ~ sfind`
- Full field regexp: `$2 ~ ("^" sfind "$")`

Full word matching gets trickier, depends on your definition of a "word", and can be served by implementation-specific constructs so I'll leave that out unless you need it.

Comment: This was the first thing I was thinking about. Also very nicely explained. You could make it slightly shorter though when you invert the logic. `BEGIN { sfind = ENVIRONMENT["sfind'] }seen[FILENAME]++ { print FILENAME, $0; next }index($2,sfind) { ARGV[ARGC++]=FILENAME; nextfile }`

Comment: @kvantour Thanks. Someone (I don't remember who, where, or when as it was probably about 20 years ago on usenet at comp.unix.shell or comp.lang.awk but I do remember being convinced) once convinced me by quoting C&V of standards that in `ARGV[ARGC++]=foo` it wasn't guaranteed that the `ARGC++` happened **after** the assignment instead of before it in all awks so I've been hesitant about using that since. Since I'm not sure but don't care enough to investigate further when I'm playing golf I use it, otherwise I don't.

Comment: I tried to use this logic but it prints all files content in the Record directory.

Comment: @maik_eshe All except the first line of each, right? Yeah, I see the bug. This is one of the reasons it's important to provide testable sample input/output in your question (and I should know better than to answer a question without it), so we have something we can test a potential solution against. I updated my answer with what I think should fix it but, of course, it's still untested since you haven't provide an example for us to test against.

Comment: @kvantour while fixing that bug it made sense to switch the order around so it now follows your suggested order.

Comment: I have modified the code can you please see it. and tell me where my mistake is?

Comment: You put `sfind=abcd` on a different line from `awk ...` so the shell won't give `awk` access to `sfind` (unless you export it which I don't recommend). When testing a script copy/paste it as-is, don't modify it then test it.

Comment: I just noticed you also put `$adress` on the line after the closing `'` of the awk script instead of on the same line so awk will read that variable as a string from stdin as input instead of reading the files listed in that variable. Again, don't modify a potential solution until after you've tested it so you can see if/when/how you break it.

Comment: finally, it works thank you. so how can I delete this file? can I get the file name?

Comment: @kvantour courtesy of a reminder from the comp.lang.awk guys - it's just `ARGV[ARGC++] = ARGV[ARGC]` that's unsafe, `ARGV[ARGC++]=FILENAME` is safe so I've updated my answer to use that.

Comment: @EdMorton do you have a link to this discussion?

Comment: @kvantour sure: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.awk/S7vrnunm57Y/TmsBAsKpAgAJ.

Answer (score 0):

Using *GNU* `grep`:

```
cat "$(grep -l abcd  *.txt | head -n 1)"
```

...or in long options form:

```
cat "$(grep --files-with-matches abcd  *.txt | head -n 1)"
```

---

To print the file name first, do:

```
n="$(grep -l abcd  *.txt | head -n 1)"
echo "-------- $n -------- "
cat "$n"
```

Comment: That would produce an error message and failure exit status from `cat` if `abcd` didn't exist in any file and it'll only print the contents of 1 file if `abcd` existed in multiple.

Comment: @EdMorton, OP's title says _"...find **a** file..."_

Comment: Yup, it certainly does and it doesn't discuss what to do if no or multiple files match.

Comment: @EdMorton, OTOH, [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62303795/6136214) is less [offensive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offensive_programming)...