# how to find a file name that contains a string "abcd " in the file content from multiple files in the directory using awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

the "bookrecords" directory has multiple files

```
bookrecords
           1.txt
           2.txt 
           3.txt .....
```

file 2.txt has the content

```
2.txt
    author: abcd
    title:  efg
    year: 1980
```

how can I get the file name 2.txt by using author: as a keyword

using awk command

I try to use grep command but I want to use awk command

```
SearchRecord()
{


  name = abcd
  total=`cat $bookrecords | grep -cwi $name`
  record=`cat $bookrecords | grep -wi $name`

  menu
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `awk`

```
$ awk -v search_string="$name" '$0~search_string{print FILENAME; exit}' bookrecords/*
```

however, I think `grep` is better if you're not structurally searching

```
$ grep -lF "$name" bookrecords/*
```

Comment: but it didn't search using the keyword "author:"

Comment: neither your example, you put name=abcd, it's the same type of search.

Comment: Naming that variable `search_string` in  the awk command is very misleading since the code is doing a regexp comparison, not a string comparison. It'll also do a partial match instead of a full match with both commands.

Comment: @EdMorton I agree that variable is misleading but I assumed person names won't contain special regex chars and partial match might be desired, therefore leading to the `grep` solution.

Comment: `J.k. Rowling` might disagree when `Jake Rowling` gets credit for her work :-). The point is that `.`s at least are common in author names and sometimes the author of an article isnt the name of a person so YMMV with chars used. My comment was just about the var name though. [I had asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62303150/how-to-find-a-file-and-delete-containing-some-string-in-the-body-using-awk-comma/62304045?noredirect=1#comment110191498_62303150) the OP to clarify their requirements in terms of full vs partial and string vs regexp matching but so far they've ignored that request.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a deep directory hierarchy below `bookrecords`, you could do a

```
grep -Elsrx '[[:space:]]*author:[[:space:]]*abcd[[:space:]]*' bookrecords
```

If you only want to look at *.txt files inside `bookrecords`, do a

```
grep -Elx '[[:space:]]*author:[[:space:]]*abcd[[:space:]]*' bookrecords/*.txt
```

The `-l` produces only the file names in the output, and `-x` takes care that the regular expression matches the whole line. Hence, a line containing *myauthor:abcde* would **not** be selected. Adapt the regexp to your taste, and be careful when replacing *abcd* by a real author name (it should not contain unescaped regexp characters, such as for instance a period).

If you want to start the line with at least one white space, and have at least one space after the colon:

```
grep -Elsrx '[[:space:]]+author:[[:space:]]+abcd[[:space:]]*' bookrecords
```